# PHP -v Command Giving Different Results Depending on My Current Directory

Tags: linux, bash, centos

OS: `CentOS 7`, 
PHP Version: `5.6'

When I run `php -v` in home directory, I get the following results

```
ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 5.6.35 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 20:30:39) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

When I run `php -v` inside of my `public_html` directory, I get these results:

```
ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 7.0.29 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 20:30:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.29, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

There are some clear differences, but my main concern is the line that shows the PHP version. Why is my `public_html` directory showing `PHP 7.0.29`??? I really need it to be the same as the other directories.

I have never seen this before, what is the issue that is causing a directory to have a different PHP version?

Comment: If you run `type php`, that would show what the shell is running when `php` is invoked. Presumably, then, that would point you to this "multiPHP Manager" and make it easier to find/identify the issue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I ran this command, and the response I got was: `php is hashed (/usr/local/bin/php)`. Where would this lead me to multiPHP Manager? I would love to know for future knowledge :)

Comment: So, what *is* `/usr/local/bin/php`? If it's a shim installed by "MultiPHP Manager", and not your real PHP binary, there's your answer. (Otherwise, make sure you're also checking `type php` as the user who's getting the other version invoked / in the pertinent directory (if the shim is hooking into `cd` and updating the `PATH` on changes), etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ahh... Interesting, thanks for the information AND the new word (shim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, it has  come to my attention that this user was set to use `PHP 7.0` through `multiPHP Manager` on my **WHM**. Odd, but that's what was causing the issue.